# Telethon (Telegram lib) giving me the session none

Tags: python-3.x, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

when i trying to save the session it is giving me the session values None

```
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient,events
import datetime


# from .telegram_config import App_api_id,App_api_hash
api_id = '*******'
api_hash = "**********"
phone_number = '+*************'


# Create a new TelegramClient with the specified session file path, API ID, and API hash
client = TelegramClient("session", api_id, api_hash)

# Start the client and establish a connection to the Telegram API using the specified phone number
client.start(phone=phone_number)

# Print the session string to the console
print(client.session.save())
```

Comment: Try `client.connect()` instead of `client.start(...)`

Comment: not work ,still geting none

Comment: `await client.connect()`. Then check `await client.is_user_authorized()`

Comment: have to add { from telethon.sessions import StringSession } also {client = TelegramClient(StringSession(), api_id, api_hash} instead of {client = TelegramClient("session", api_id, api_hash)}

Comment: Now facing another problem `from telethon.sync import TelegramClient,events
from telethon.sessions import StringSession
import datetime
# from .telegram_config import App_api_id,App_api_hash
api_id = '********'
api_hash = "******"
key="****"
phone_number = '******'


client = TelegramClient(StringSession(key), api_id, api_hash)

# Start the client and establish a connection to the Telegram API using the specified phone number
client.start(phone=phone_number)

# Print the session string to the console
print(client.session.save()) `

Comment: Server sent a very new message with ID 13********, ignoring

Comment: The default session type does not return anything on save. [The documentation on Session Files](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/stable/concepts/sessions.html) have working examples.

Answer (score -1):

#you can generate the session using below code

from telethon.sync import TelegramClient,events

from telethon.sessions import StringSession

api_id = '***'

api_hash = "*******"

phone_number = '*******'

#Create a new TelegramClient with the specified session file path, API ID, and API hash

client = TelegramClient(StringSession(), api_id, api_hash)

#Start the client and establish a connection to the Telegram API using the specified phone number

client.start(phone=phone_number)